# Send form to local server with fetch() POST failed. Error 405

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, http-status-code-405

I would like to send a filled out form in JSON format via [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) POST to a local server, which has been set up with "[npm http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)". The server has been started with the command "http-server --cors". Error message when clicking on the submit button is: "*405 (Method Not Allowed)*". I tried it in Chrome and Edge.

I am a bit overwhelmed now. Is it related to the CORS security settings? Do I need a server side node.js script to allow this call? Is it because I only use a local server? I'm lost...

Any help is highly appreciated! Very new to all this but I am eager to learn.

Below is the JSON and the JavaScript code. Both are in the same main directory on the local server:

JSON:

```
    [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Rick",
    "email":"rick@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Glenn",
    "email":"glenn@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Negan",
    "email":"negan@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

HTML file to show the JSON and upload a new entry:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fetch API Sandbox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Fetch API Sandbox</h1>
  <button id="getUsers">Get JSON</button>

  <div id="output"></div>
  <!--Hier wird das JSON reingeschrieben-->

  <form id="addPost">
    <div> <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="ID"> </div>
    <div> <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"> </div>
    <div> <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail"> </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('getUsers').addEventListener('click', getUsers);
    document.getElementById('addPost').addEventListener('submit', addPost);

    function getUsers() {
      fetch('users.json')
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.ok)
            return response.json();
          else
            throw new Error("Names could not be loaded!")
        })
        .then(function(json) {
          console.log(json);
          let output = '<h2>Users</h2>';
          json.forEach(function(user) {
            output += `
    <ul>
      <li>ID: ${user.id}</li>
      <li>Name: ${user.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${user.email}</li>
    </ul>
     `;
            console.log(output);
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
          });
        })
    }

    function addPost(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let id = document.getElementById('id').value;
      //console.log(id);
      let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      let email = document.getElementById('email').value;

      fetch('users.json', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            name: name,
            email: email
          })
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are your current CORS settings on server side?

Comment: Is your api and the ui server url different?

Comment: @Kushal the html and JSON are both on http://localhost:8080, so API and ui server are similar, I suppose.

Comment: Can you please paste one of the apis response headers over here?

Comment: @DevangNaghera I have no script on the server side. So don't really know how to check that. The local server has been start with http-server --cors. This "--cors" means "Enable CORS via the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header". This is all I know.

Comment: @Kushal the problem is, that I only used a static server. Thanks for helping, anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http-server` is a static files server. It will only handle `GET` requests.

However, you are in luck, because there is a similar package, which allows you to run a RESTful API with a single command. It's called [`json-server`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). You only need to provide a JSON file which will take the role of your "database". In your case the JSON can look like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Rick",
      "email": "rick@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Glenn",
      "email": "glenn@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Negan",
      "email": "negan@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

When you run the server with `json-server db.json` this will create GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE method handlers for the endpoint `/users`. You will then be able to get/insert/alter/delete records from the "database". In your case, the `fetch` call endpoint URL has to be changed to: `fetch('localhost:3000/users', ...)`.

You can install the package globally by running `npm install -g json-server`.

Comment: Thanks very much, Tsvetan! Works perfectly. I guess there is still a lot to learn, if I ever want to deploy a project to the net...